# Radio buttons and e-mails

Tags: php, html

Here's the overall outcome of what I am going for.

Two radio buttons - Suggestion and Complaint

If suggestion is checked (which it is by default) Send to xyz e-mail.
If Complaint is check - send to xyz e-mail AND abc e-mail.

The code is in two files html and php. The form on the html calls the php file.
HTML Part

```
input type="radio" id="Suggestion" name="radiob" checked onClick="toggleDiv2"/
input type="radio" id="Complaint" name="radiob" onClick="toggleDiv('ifcomplaint')"/
```

PHP part

```
$mailto = 'xyz-email' ;
```

Doesn't matter if JS has to be involved. I'll do it any way it works. I just cant seem to set it up so it sends to another e-mail based on the radio button selection.

Comment: Your question is kind of scattered... makes it hard to answer specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add value="1" for the first radio button and value="2" for the second radio button.
Now on php side check

```
$radioValue=$_POST['radiob'];
if($radioValue==1){
send to xyz
}
else{
send to both
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the radio buttons `value` attributes, then you can test `$_POST['radiob']`.